# polynomials such that $P(k)=Q(l)$ for all integer $k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

In a book I have read this problem:

> Given $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, if $P(X)$ takes at every integer, a value which is the $k$-th power of an integer, then $P(X)$ itself is the $k$-th power of a polynomial. Formally if:
> $$\begin{align}\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\exists l\in \mathbb{Z}&& P(n)=l^k \end{align}$$
> then $\exists R(X)\,\, P(x)=R(X)^k$

we can find a proof in this [paper](http://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Esury/polys.pdf) page $8$.

Is the following assertion true:

> Given a polynomials $Q$ with integer coefficients,If $P(X)$ takes at every integer, a value which is of the form $Q(k)$ for an integer k, then $P(X)=Q(R(X))$ for a polynomial $R$ polynomial. Formally if:
> $$\begin{align}\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\exists l\in \mathbb{Z}&& P(n)=Q(l) \end{align}$$
> then $\exists R(X)\,\, P(x)=Q(R(X))$

I need some suggestions to solve this problem,or any references and sources which deal with this sort of problems. thaks

Comment: do you require $R$ to have integer coefficients ?

Comment: R may not have integer coefficients, take for example $P(x)=(x(x+1))/2)^2+1$ for every integer $n$ P(n) is of the form $k^2+1$ and here $R(x)=x(x+1)/2$

Comment: oh right, i guess this also works with $Q(x) = x$ and $P(x) = x(x+1)/2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following: $ $ H. Davenport; D. Lewis; A. Schinzel, [Polynomials of certain special types](https://eudml.org/doc/207456), *Acta Arithmetica* (1964) 107-116.