# If $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $f(f(x)),f(f(f(x)))\in\mathbb Z[x]$ prove that $f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, contest-math

> If a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $$f(f(x)),f(f(f(x)))\in\mathbb Z[x]$$
> prove that $f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$.

This problem is from 2019 Japan Mathematical Olympiad: see problem 9 (the third day last problem) https://www.imojp.org/archive/mo2019/selection_camp/problems/2019.pdf

Here is what I tried:: Let $f(x)=\dfrac{P(x)}{d}$ where $P(x)\in\mathbb Z[x],d$ is the common denominator of the coefficients of $f(x)$. If let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^i,a_{i}\in\mathbb Z$, then we have
$$f(f(x))=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}}{d^i}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^i\right)^i\in\mathbb Z[x]$$
and $f(f(f(x)))$ is very ugly, so how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know if this helps but noting $\circ^n f = f \circ f \cdots \circ f$, the hypothesis that both $\circ^2 f$ and $\circ^3 f$ have integer coefficients gives actually $\circ^n f \in \Bbb Z[X]$ for all $n$; you can prove this by induction on $n$ using that $\circ^n f = f(\circ^{n-1}f)$, you'll need one case for odd $n$ and the other for $n$ even.

Comment: See [this answer](/a/3793314) by Doctor Who.

Comment: @user10354138, you link it's different problem?because this problem have two condition: it's $f(f(x)),f(f(f(x)))\in Z[x]$.the problem is  same polynomial.

Comment: in other words,if$f(x)\in Q[x]$,and  $f(f(x))\in Z[x]$ I think we can't have $f(x)\in Z[x]$

Comment: As user10354138 suggested, this answer by Doctor Who (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793239/can-composition-of-integer-polynomial-and-rational-polynomial-with-a-non-integer/3793314#3793314) applied with $p=f \circ f, q=f$, shows that if
some coefficient denominator is divisible by a prime that doesn't divide the leading coefficient (which must be integer) and $f \circ f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ then $f \circ f \circ f \notin \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: I answered this question at Mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379323/pmx-in-mathbbzx-implies-px-in-mathbbzx/379420#379420 .

Comment: @DavidESpeyer May I , with your permission, create a community Wiki post detailing the same answer? I wish to see this question answered. I know all the definitions, and will provide the required links. I may also add an approach of my own sometime later if I can, only in a separate answer.

Comment: Sure, go ahead! @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Thank you so much David. You have given me the opportunity to learn something new, I appreciate that.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Aha, so all we need to know about $g^{(3)}$ is that $g^{(3)}(0) \in \mathbb Z$. Spectacular.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Done, you may take a look. Kindly feel free to edit the answer, and please add any links you feel are important. I absolutely loved writing the answer below and researching it, so thank you once more. I'd like to know if the answer is "research level" or if it can be found in standard textbooks on the subject.

Comment: Looks nice, thanks for adding all this detail!

Comment: I very much doubt this is in any standard textbook. I imagine this argument could be published in a not very good number theory journal, were it not for the fact that there is apparently an elementary solution somewhere in Japan!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you very much for your feedback. Much appreciated. I cannot believe I have just seen an argument not out of a textbook, it feels like I'm in dreamland.

Comment: @DavidLampert The answer you mentioned assumes that p is monic which is not necessarily the case in this problem.

Comment: @user26857 The argument in the referenced answer works if the leading coefficient is a p-adic unit.

Comment: @DavidLampert I am not sure I can understand how this solves the present question.

Comment: @user26857 My comment was a partial answer.  The condition on $f \circ f$ implies that the leading coefficent of $f$ must be an integer, and my comment explains that the argument in the referenced answer shows that if a prime $p$ doesn't divide the leading coefficient of $f$ (so the leading coefficient is a unit in $\mathbb Z_p$) then all coefficients belong to $\mathbb Z_p$ so $p$ can't divide the denominator of any coefficient of $f$.  Bravo David Speyer and Teresa Lisbon for the complete answer... and I'd still like to see the 5 line solution!

Comment: @DavidLampert Still searching, I will inform you if I can get one!

Comment: these days ,I  have read a few solution ,that used to seem to feel some advanced knowledge, I hope I can get some answers from the official solution,Thanks

Answer (score 12):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\mathtt{\underline{\large{#1}}}}$ This answer can be found in the Math Overflow post by David Speyer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379323/pmx-in-mathbbzx-implies-px-in-mathbbzx/379420#379420). I give him due credit for it in the comments. I wish to bring to the notice of everybody the arguments used here, so they may attempt to use it in the future. I request feedback from people who wish for me to elaborate on further things.

##### The Newton Polygon of a $p$-adic polynomial

The Newton polygon of a polynomial has many uses : probably the most relatable use is to prove that the polynomial is irreducible if one can locate the roots of the polynomial. Please read the answer by Captain Lama [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671738/explaining-newton-polygon-for-proving-irreducibility-of-polynomial-in-mathbbz) for more details on the Newton polygon and its uses.

Nevertheless, we must extend the notion provided in the linked post. For this purpose, I will require knowledge of the following notions.

- The $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$. Details can be found on the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).
- The $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$, which is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q_p$, and to be fair is not a stretch away from $\mathbb Q_p$ in terms of the definition. See the Wolfram Mathworld post [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicInteger.html).
- The $p$-adic valuation $\nu$ , which may have a couple of different definitions, but in the case of this answer is defined as the biggest integer $e$ such that $p^e$ divides that number. Basically, if we express the number as a traditional $p$-adic sum, then the smallest non-zero index of the sum is the valuation. There is some confusion regarding this since an alternate definition is also known : you can see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45150/what-is-the-p-adic-valuation-of-a-number) for some details. I will use the given definition.
- The notion of an algebraic closure of a field, which $\mathbb Q_p$ is. One can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field) for details. We call the (unique up to isomorphism) algebraic closure as $\mathbb Q_p^{alg}$.
- The fact that the $p$-adic valuation extends to a valuation on $\mathbb Q_p^{alg}$. This is explained by David and many others [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30581/extension-of-valuation).

Before going into things , some motivation. The reason we wish to go into $\mathbb Q_p$ is because, by a coefficient-to-coefficient mapping ,it is easy to figure out a map from $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z_p[x]$. Furthermore, note that if a polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ for all primes $p$ then $g(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$, since one can see the contrapositive by taking the LCM of denominators or any prime dividing the denominator.

> *Definition* : Let $f = f_0 + f_1x + ... + f_dx^d$  be a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q_p$. The Newton polygon of $f$ is the lower convex hull of the points $(0,\nu(f_0)), ..., (d,\nu(f_d))$. That is, it is the unique piecewise straight line path , such that each of these points either lies above the path or on the path, the points corresponding to $0$ and $d$ must lie on the path, and the path can be non-linear only at the given points. Examples can be found on the Wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon).

Now, the Newton polygon has slopes associated to it, which are the slopes of the lines forming it. Suppose that the polygon passes through $(j,N_j)$ for $0 \leq j \leq d$. The quantities $s_j = N_j - N_{j-1}$ are called the slopes of the polygon, and by convexity, $s_1 \leq s_2 \leq ... \leq s_d$. (Note : If one wishes to try , please calculate the slope sequence of $P(x) = 1+5x + \frac 15 x^2 + 35x^3$ with respect to the $5$-adic valuation : the Newton polygon is on the Wiki page. I will hide the answer below.)

Note that a slope sequence , along with the location of the left and rightmost points, uniquely determine the polygon.

Before moving , one notation : $\mathbb Q_p[x]$ is the set of all polynomials having coefficients in $\mathbb Q_p$, and likewise $\mathbb Z_p[x]$.

##### Two results concerning the Newton Polygon

What's beautiful about the Newton polygon is the fact that you can figure out the Newton polygon of a product of polynomials, from the Newton polygon of the individual polynomials. The reason why this is true is that the coefficients of the product can be easily described in terms of the coefficients of the individual polynomials, and then one just needs to do a little bit of hard work figuring out the details. The details may be found in the paper linked [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869300985867#:%7E:text=A%20polynomial%20is%20absolutely%20irreducible,the%20well%2Dknown%20Eisenstein%20criterion.).

> *Ostrowski's lemma* (OL) : Let $f,f'$ be $p$-adic polynomials with slope sequences $s_1,...,s_n$ and $t_1,...,t_m$ respectively. Then the slope sequence of $ff'$ is the sequence $s_1,...,s_n,t_1,...,t_m$ sorted in ascending order.

The next fact links the roots of $f$, which will lie in the algebraic closure $\mathbb Q_p^{alg}$. Recall that these roots have a valuation. The next result is a genius result. There is a proof in Matthew Baker's notes, and an otherwise excellent explanation of another result, in his blog post [here](https://mattbaker.blog/2014/05/02/newton-polygons-and-galois-groups/).

> *The fundamental theorem of the Newton polygon* (FNTP) : Let $f$ be a $p$-adic polynomial and $\theta_1,...,\theta_d$ be the roots which lie in $\mathbb Q_p^{alg}$. Then , up to a reordering of the roots, we have $\nu(\theta_j) = -s_j$.

Truly astonishing : this links the $p$-adic values of the coefficients to the $p$-adic values of the roots of the polynomial, via the slopes of the Newton polygon. You can see why this result is so amazing : to link coefficients to roots , all you need is the Newton polygon!

All this serves to illustrate the really powerful machinery we are working with. Indeed, if I were to provide a proof sketch now of the theorem stated by the OP, then I would say this : using the Newton polygon of $f$, we can compute part of the Newton polygon of $f \circ f$. The answer then uses the link between the roots of $f$ and $f \circ f$ , and then from the FTNP transfers to the link between the coefficients of these polynomials, which is what we want to study. So a condition on the coefficients of $f$ becomes a condition on the coefficients of $f \circ f$ and so on.

##### The main lemma

The main lemma proved by David is the following :

> Let $f \in \mathbb Q_p[x]$ not have all its coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$ , but have the constant term $f_0 \in \mathbb Z_p$. Then $f \circ f$ cannot have all its coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$.

Proof : Note that when we write $f = f_0 +... + f_dx^d$, we get $f \circ f = f_0 + ... + f_d^{d+1}x^{d^2}$. So the leading term is $f_d^{d+1}$. Clearly if $f_d \notin \mathbb Z_p$ then $f_d^{d+1} \notin \mathbb Z_p$, and we are done. Therefore we assume that $f_d \in \mathbb Z_p$.

What can we infer about the Newton polynomial of $f$? Well, $\nu(f_0) , \nu(f_d) \geq 0$, but by assumption one of $f$'s coefficients is not an integer, so $\nu(f_j) < 0$ for some $j$. Thus, the Newton polygon of $f$ strictly dips below zero to accommodate $(j,\nu(f_j))$, and then recovers. This means that the polygon slopes are first negative and then positive : we can order them as $s_1 \leq s_2 \leq ... \leq s_k < 0 < s_{k+1} \leq ... \leq s_d$. Then $(k,N_k)$ is the lowermost point of the Newton polygon. Note that $N_k <0$  since it is the lowermost point and we know that the polygon comes below zero. We keep track of this fact.

Using FTNC, let us get the roots of $f$, labelled so that $\nu(\theta_j) = -s_j$. Make now a very key observation, which links back to the proof sketch I gave :
$$
f(x) = f_d \prod_{j} (x-\theta_j) \implies f\circ f(x) = f_d \prod_{j} (f(x)-\theta_j)
$$

and therefore $f \circ f(x)$ has been expressed as a product of polynomials, whose Newton polygons can be ascertained. We are firmly in OL territory. However, we must break into two cases, for $j$ being on the left and right hand side of $k$ on the polygon.

Let me first explain what we are trying to achieve in the next few lines : essentially, $f \circ f \notin \mathbb Z_p[x]$ means that the Newton polygon of $f \circ f$ dips below the $x$-axis somewhere, since wherever it dips, the coefficient can't be a $p$-adic integer. So we need to study height changes among the slopes of the polygons of $f(x)-\theta_j$ and transfer them to that of $f \circ f$ using OL.

- If $1 \leq j \leq k$, then $\nu(\theta_j) \geq 0$. The constant term of $f - \theta_j$ is $f_0 - \theta_j$ , which by the ultrametric nature of the valuation will have a non-negative valuation. The other coefficients don't change. In particular, the increasing part of the slope sequence of $f$ is retained by $f - \theta_j$, and remains $(s_{k+1},...,s_d)$. Thus, the height change of the Newton polygon of $f-\theta_j$ between  $(k,N_k)$ and $(d,N_d)$ is $s_{k+1} + ... + s_d = N_d - N_k$.
- If $k+1 \leq j \leq d$ then $\nu(\theta_j) < 0$. The constant term of $f-\theta_j$ is $\nu(f - \theta_j) = \nu(\theta_j)  = -s_j< 0$ by the ultrametric property of the valuation. The right hand end point is $(d,N_d)$. Thus, the height change of the Newton polygon of $f-\theta_j$ between $(k,N_k)$ and $(d,N_d)$ is at least $N_d + s_j$, since the polygon will dip at $(0,-s_j)$ and then go up. It turns out the estimate is sufficient.

Now, we are trying to find the dip of $f \circ f$ from the right endpoint, and if this dip is more than the right endpoint's y coordinate, we are done. By OL, we know that all the slopes of $f(x)-\theta_j$ are to be sorted into increasing order, and for finding the lowest point of the Newton polygon of $f \circ f$ we need to find the non-negative slopes and add them together to get the total drop.

What are those non-negative slopes? Well, there's those from $1 \leq j \leq k$, giving a total drop by $N_d - N_k$, and there are $k$ of those, giving a combined drop of $k(N_d - N_k)$ from these cases. For $k+1 \leq j \leq d$, we have a drop of at least $N_d + s_j$ in each case. Finally the total drop is at least $k(N_d - N_k) + \sum_{j=k+1}^d (N_d + s_j)$.

Recall that the leading term of $f \circ f$ is $f_d^{d+1}$. Using the multiplicative property of the valuation , we get that the right endpoint of the Newton polygon of $f \circ f$ is $(d^2, \nu(f_d^{d+1})) = (d^2,N_d(d+1))$.

So, we are left to ask ourselves : is $k(N_d - N_k) + \sum_{j=k+1}^d (N_d + s_j) > N_d(d+1)$?

> Exercise you can give your children : Provide them the context, and let them prove that $$k(N_d - N_k) + \sum_{j=k+1}^d (N_d + s_j) - N_d(d+1) = -(k+1)N_k$$

which is a positive quantity since $N_k < 0$. Therefore, the dip is more than the right endpoint! So the Newton polygon of $f_j$ goes below the $x$ axis at some point : and exhale.

##### The main theorem

The main theorem can be stated and proved easily now.

> Let $g$ have coefficients in $\mathbb Q_p$ and let $g \circ g , g \circ g \circ g $ have coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$. Then $g$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Proof : Note that $g(g(0)), g(g(g(0)))  \in \mathbb Z_p$, these are the constant terms of the respective polynomials. Let $f(x) = g(x + g(g(0))) - g(g(0))$. Now, note that $$
f \circ f(x) = g(g(x + g(g(0)))) - g(g(0))  = g \circ g( x + g \circ g(0)) - g \circ g(0)
$$

is a difference of polynomials in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ hence belongs in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$. Finally, $f(0) = g \circ g \circ g(0) - g \circ g(0)$, hence $f(0) \in \mathbb Z_p$. By the contrapositive of the main lemma , we get that $f$ has coefficients in $Z_p$ (if not, then the main lemma would be contradicted).

But then $g$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$ too, from the following logic : if $f$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$,then so does $f - g(g(0))$. But then this is just a $g(g(0))$ shift of the polynomial $g(x)$, and any $\mathbb Z_p$ integer shift retains coefficient membership in $\mathbb Z_p$ from a simple binomial theorem type argument and the ultrametric nature of the valuation.

Thus, we are done. But we can go one step further. Define $h^{(r)}$ to be the $r$-fold composition of $h$, with $h^{(1)} = h$.

> Let $h \in \mathbb Q_p[x]$ and $k_1,k_2$ be relatively prime such that $h^{k_1},h^{k_2} \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ for relatively prime $k_1,k_2$. Then $h \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$.

Proof : Compositions retain membership of coefficients in $\mathbb Z_p$, so from Bezout's lemma with $k_1$ and $k_2$, we conclude that if $S = \{r : h^r \notin Z_p[x]\}$ then $S$ is bounded above. Let $r  = \max S$. But then from the previous theorem, $2r,3r \notin S$ so $r \notin S$ as well, a contradiction. Thus, $S$ must be empty i.e. $1 \notin S$, as desired.

##### Back to our problem

We haven't addressed the OP's problem yet! We will do that easily.

> Let $f(f(x)) , f(f(f(x))) \in \mathbb Z[x]$. Then $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$.

Proof : Well, $f(f(x)) , f(f(f(x))) \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ for all primes $p$, so $f(x) \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ for all primes $p$, and hence $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$.

> Exercise you can give your children : if for co-prime $k_1,k_2$ we have $f^{(k_1)},f^{(k_2)} \in \mathbb Z[x]$ then $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$.

Well , that was worth it. There's another extension we can make as well.

> Let $k_1,...,k_n$ be positive numbers such that $\gcd(k_1,...,k_n) = 1$. Then if $h^{(k_i)} \in \mathbb Z[x]$ for all $x$ then $h \in \mathbb Z[x]$.

Proof : Let $S = \{k : h^{(k)} \in \mathbb Z[x]\}$. Since each $k_i \in S$ we know that $k_i$ is closed under positive linear combinations. Thus two consecutive numbers will be contained in $S$ by a generalization of Bezout's lemma. Then we apply the child case, and we are done!

This result helps , for example, if none of the $k_i$ are pairwise coprime : for example, if $h^{(6)}, h^{(15)} , h^{(21)} \in \mathbb Z[x]$ then $h \in \mathbb Z[x]$.

##### Conclusions

The theory of Newton polygons is useful, since the fundamental lemma helps link the coefficients and roots of a polynomial together, and then OL helps in putting together the Newton polynomial for product polynomials. Aside from what we've done here, the theory can be used to prove a large number of irreducibility results and can give information about the nature of the Galois groups of the extension formed by the splitting field of polynomials over fields, see Baker's blog for the same.

But somewhere in Japan, I am sure they have a five-line solution waiting for me.

Comment: Nice use of a fairly elementary part of the theory of the p-adic numbers (valued fields). @Teresa Lisbon says at the end of her answer “*But somewhere in Japan, I am sure they have a five-line solution waiting for me.*”
I would like to know one or more correct answers given by tennagers, smart participants in the Japanese Olympiad in which this problem was proposed.

Comment: ”But somewhere in Japan, I am sure they have a five-line solution waiting for me.”       I'm looking forward to seeing such solutions